# Parsing forum posts with python3 and beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to get the text from the forum posts.
The site is this one: 
http://forum.pcekspert.com/showthread.php?t=263544

I tried to do it like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create a variable with the url
url = 'http://forum.pcekspert.com/showthread.php?t=263544'

# Use requests to get the contents
r = requests.get(url)

# Get the text of the contents
html_content = r.text

# Convert the html content into a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")

rez = soup.find_all('id=\"__xclaimwords_wrapper\"')

print(rez)
```

From the html of the file I found out that the post message is in two tags.

TEXT

the xxx in the first id is a number with 7 digits and every post message has a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a css select to find the dic with the `__xclaimwords_wrapper` ids and pull the text from that, that is where the message text is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")

rez = [d.text for d in soup.select("#__xclaimwords_wrapper")]
```

Outout:

```
['Izgleda da novi update za 8 pod nazivom Threshold ce zapravo biti win9.. pa ako nekoga zanima više malo evo vam linka : http://www.pcgamer.com/2014/01/20/wi...ame=0&ns_fee=0\r\ni malo opsirnije o threshold-u http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/th...hip-april-2015', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Sneaky\n\n\nIzgleda da novi update za 8 pod nazivom Threshold ce zapravo biti win9.. pa ako nekoga zanima više malo evo vam linka : http://www.pcgamer.com/2014/01/20/wi...ame=0&ns_fee=0\r\ni malo opsirnije o threshold-u http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/th...hip-april-2015\n\n\n\nIzgleda da su prihvatili logiku Appla i da stancaju verzije i malo po malo "cokaju", nekako mi se cini logicnije nego svako 5 g izbacivat op OS koji u danasnem svitu androida/iosa/wpa teze prolazi naplatu. Nije da su direktno usporedivi, ali ljudi su drski pa je tesko odvojit vece pare za OS.', 'Ja bi prije rekao da su shvatili da su malo zaj* za Win8, pa da isprave stetu - lakse je izbaciti novu verziju.\nSlicno kao i sa Vistom.', 'Tocno to. Win8 (8.1) je meni osobno isto kao i WinME i Vista. U biti MS napravi svaku drugu generaciju Winsa kvalitetno jer popravlja prethodnu koju za*ere maksimalno sa novim features-ima ', 'Nek oni meni samo refreshaju izgled desktopa sa novim ikonama, explorer elementima i animacijama i ja sam zadovoljan \n\nI da, još bolju cloud i WP9 integraciju.', 'Da, fakat je idiocki izbacivat Service packove, kad možeš pičiti nove OS-ove \n\nKako ono beše:\nWin 2000 - SP4\nWin XP - SP3\nVista - SP2\nWin 7 - SP1\nWin 8 - Win 8.1   ', 'meni više smeta to što još nisu uveli novi filesystem koji se mislim da još od viste obećava, a ne nekakve vizualne gluposti', 'nije se nista obecavalo od viste\r\nono sto je bio WinFS nije bio novi FS nego NTFS + "layer" baze podataka koja je vukla metadata iz fajlova\n\r\nmozes si to sranje i instalirat na xp-u (beta 1) pa vidjet sta je to\n\r\nu svakom slucaju ja preskacem i win9\r\nsumnjam da ce ista novog pridonjeti ako ne i jos gore cim pocne sve vise integracija sranja koje nitko normalan netreba\n\r\nako se nevaram win8 ima strgani nacin loginova (slagalica, face reckognition), nebi se cudio da 9-tka bude samo profinjenija 8-ica\r\nsa popravljenim tim stvarima\r\ncak bi i ReFS mogao vidjeti svjetlost posto ga samo nude na serverima kao test\n\r\nali to su samo minarne stvari, to mene ne zanima :P\r\nak  ce jasit i dalje metro sranja i tviter i assbook integracije i bing pizd***e\r\nonda ostajem na 7-ici ', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Drug Brko\n\n\nWin 2000 - SP4\n\n\n\nSa zadnjim rollupom, skoro 5, ali uzmi da je NT 4 imao 6+1 komada, tako da ti je tablica dobra. ', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Bubba\n\n\nSa zadnjim rollupom, skoro 5, ali uzmi da je NT 4 imao 6+1 komada, tako da ti je tablica dobra. \n\n\n\nMa znam da je bio rollup za win2000, sjećam se da sam 2005 slipstreamao cd sa tim updateom, al nije SP. \nXP SP3 nakon instalacije OS-a ima još oko 1GB updateova sa neta, Win 7 isto. Vjerojatno i vista \nSad će bit za win 8.1 bit 100 MB i odma će doći win 9 ', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Drug Brko\n\n\nMa znam da je bio rollup za win2000, sjećam se da sam 2005 slipstreamao cd sa tim updateom, al nije SP.\n\n\n\nnije SP jer oni nisu htjeli da bude SP\r\njer kad izbace SP onda moraju produljiti rok podrske OS-a\n\r\nzato XP i nece imati SP4 iako ima tonu patcheva nakon SP3-a\r\nkao sto i vista nece dobit SP3 a win "7" SP2\n\r\nsvaki SP ih kosta minimalno novih 3 godina podrske sto se neuklapa u njihovu ideju\r\nsvake 2 godine novi OS\n\r\nzasto bi davali besplatne SP-ove kad mogu u istom roku naplacivati novi OS', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Baja 001\n\n\nIzgleda da su prihvatili logiku Appla i da stancaju verzije i malo po malo "cokaju", nekako mi se cini logicnije nego svako 5 g izbacivat op OS koji u danasnem svitu androida/iosa/wpa teze prolazi naplatu. Nije da su direktno usporedivi, ali ljudi su drski pa je tesko odvojit vece pare za OS.\n\n\n\nS druge strane, Appleovi updateovi se više ne naplaćuju. Prvo su smanjili cijenu, a 10.9 je besplatan. Dovoljno je kupit hardware.', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor IcyTexx\n\n\nS druge strane, Appleovi updateovi se više ne naplaćuju. Prvo su smanjili cijenu, a 10.9 je besplatan. Dovoljno je kupit hardware.\n\n\n\nNaplati se kroz hw, ali svakako idu na taj mobilni trend izbacivanja.', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor IcyTexx\n\n\nS druge strane, Appleovi updateovi se više ne naplaćuju. Prvo su smanjili cijenu, a 10.9 je besplatan. Dovoljno je kupit hardware.\n\n\n\nS druge strane appleovi updateovi su smeće. To ti kažem s punom odgovornošću kao dugogodišnji profesionalni korisnik (FCP7 itd.). Trenutno imamo predzadnju generaciju njihovih Mac Pro 6 jezgrenih đubradi i nakon upgrejda na Mavericse sve je ošlo u tri pm. Popis je predugačak...a imaš dovoljno o tome i na netu.\n\n\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Baja 001\n\n\nNaplati se kroz hw, ali svakako idu na taj mobilni trend izbacivanja.\n\n\n\nTako je. Dovoljno je baciti oko na cjenik.', 'Zato kažem dovoljno je kupit hardware... U Americi su im laptopi pojeftinili. Kad ću ići sad u 5. mj u Ameriku opet ću kupit jednog jer sam im voljan dati taj price premium. Prije dvije godine sam im dao više radi kvalitete izrade, a kroz korištenje sad bi im dao više radi OS-a. Vise ne naplaćuju ni svoj "Office" software. Gledao sam i u PC svijetu ne mogu naći zamjenu njihovom 15" MBP Retina. Barem po mojim kriterijima. Ako netko nadje "retina" laptop od 15" koji je jednako debeo kao i MBPR, da je metalan, a ne plastican, sa mu jednako ili duže traje baterija, istih ili jačih specifikacija sa PCIE storageom za iste ili manje pare skidam mu kapu. A od Windowsovih DPI postavki mi bude zlo.\n\nS druge strane, Windows 8 kosta $120. A on je cvijeće, ha? Osnovni Office $130. Evo čekam u redu da im iskeširam pare...\n\nNo neću sad ulazit u to budući da je ovo MS tema, samo ce se krenut ljutit ljudi.\n\n@gnujko vjerujem ti, mene nije zahvatilo bas puno problema kod Mavericksa, a isto nisam "običan" korisnik. Budem pogledao o kakvim se problemima tu radi.', 'moguce je da windows 8.2 ne bude 8.2 nego windows 9\nali nadam se da ce poboljsat i destop i metro u isto vrijeme jer dosta stvari koje na destopu imas nema u metrou sto bi stvarno koristilo pogotovo samo za RT verziju kao npr explorer\n\nali budemo vidjeli, brat mi je bio na mvp summitu i nisu puno govorili o novim windowsima', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Metlina\n\n\ni nisu puno govorili o novim windowsima\n\n\n\nzato sto ih jos nisu ni poceli "raditi"\r\nsad se jos uvjek fokusiraju na ovo: http://wzascok.livejournal.com/12774.html', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor Metlina\n\n\nmoguce je da windows 8.2 ne bude 8.2 nego windows 9\nali nadam se da ce poboljsat i destop i metro u isto vrijeme jer dosta stvari koje na destopu imas nema u metrou sto bi stvarno koristilo pogotovo samo za RT verziju kao npr explorer\n\nali budemo vidjeli, brat mi je bio na mvp summitu i nisu puno govorili o novim windowsima\n\n\n\n100% ne bude bilo Win8.2, ide se na Threshold (Windows 9).\n\nImaš Metro verziju File Managera, SkyDrive (OneDrive).\n\nMVP-ovi su pod NDA pa nit ne smiju pričati o takvim stvarima \n\nEDIT: I Threshold je počeo sa developmentom.', 'http://youtu.be/VF4Eva_4UNE', '\n\r\nnije 9 nego 10 \n\r\nslike i tekst http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2014...es-windows-10/\n\r\nstižu sredinom 2015.', 'Jednostavno smo priznali da smo zajebali ', 'Tema bi se trebala preimenovat u Windows 10 ', '\n\n\n\n\nvolio bih zamijeniti sedmicu, vidjet ćemo sada hoću li ', 'Odlicno, taman dovoljno dugo dok ne izguram ove w7 sa zaobilazenjem w8  \n\n90-tih sam furo windows 3.1 pa nesto jako malo W95 a koristio  W98, WNT tj. W2000 smo isto zaobisli pa WXP, SP1 i SP2 a SP3 i W Vistu isto debelo zaobisao. \n\nMislim da mi je windows vista najgore legla od svih ti windowsa.\nE sad ostaje nada da ce ovi w10 biti na razini w7...', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor mamutarka\n\n\nhttp://youtu.be/VF4Eva_4UNE\n\n\n\nNe kuzim, kao, ovo je neki "novi" super feature?\n\r\nOpen/CreateWindowsStation() i Create/SwitchDesktop() su funkcije podrzane u Windows API-ju jos od Windowsa 2000, dakle, cijelih 14 godina, rekli bi smo - old news.\n\r\nDrugim rijecima, svaki nemusti programer je mogao napraviti ovo bez nekih vecih problema i poteskoca, sto i jesu radili jer ovakvi programcici postoje "oduvijek".\n\r\nNadam se da ipak imaju u planu neki novi ozbiljniji feature, tipa WinFS ili stogod drugo, jer ovo je smijesno i za pokazivati, a kamo li stavljati kao novi ficur novih Windowsa... :\\', 'http://youtu.be/84NI5fjTfpQ', 'http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwin...ng-windows-10/', 'mergao dvije teme, windows 9 i windows 10 u jednu...\nOvdje će izaći tech preview:\nhttp://windows.microsoft.com/hr-hr/w...ew-coming-soon', 'Čim vidim ono tablet sučelje, imam osjećaj da neću mjenjat sedmicu još ohoho', '\nCitiraj:\n\n\n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAutor ivan77\n\n\nČim vidim ono tablet sučelje, imam osjećaj da neću mjenjat sedmicu još ohoho\n\n\n\nBezveze si skeptičan, meni se na kraju i svidio metro. Pogotovo što imaš aplikacije iz store-a koje su prilično zanimljive, od nogometnih rezultata preko tečajne liste do aplikacije koja streama svjetske televizije tipa BBC bez da ti treba proxy, hola i slično.']
```

Which matches what you see on the page.

Comment: Is there a way that I can output every comment in one row? This way is all glued together.

Comment: It is not all glued together,  each element is the text from eac row